# Android ListView with Edittext and AdjustResize losing focus

Tags: android, listview, lostfocus

After a lot of research I still haven't found a solution for the following problem:

My ListView consists of EditTexts to input a variable amount of fields. When one of them is selected, the focus is lost when they keyboard shows.
Using AdjustPan would work, however I have an important Button under the list, that would get hidden, so I need to find a solution with AdjustResize that works.
Like often suggested I tried posting a delayed Runnable to regain focus, and to play around with ListViews descendantFocusability. This only worked in 50% of the cases, which seems to be a problem with timing.

Any ideas, suggestions or explanations would be very much appreciated

Comment: Don't use edit text at list view item

Comment: did you try to set focus to false for all UI objects? (+ you can hide the keyboard if it's help..)

Comment: Using a LinearLayout in a Scrollview causes problems scrolling to a specific position and so on
@AsfK well the keyboard is supposed to show, so the user can input some text, but with focus being lost he types but nothing happens